# Emacs Clojure mode without paredit

Tags: emacs, clojure, paredit

I'm using the Clojure mode package from ELPA. Otherwise everything is fine, but I just can't stand paredit mode. I can't seem to turn it off easily, now I just disable it for every buffer I open. I tried setting this variable to nil:

```
(setq clojure-enable-paredit nil)
```

But paredit still appears. Any ideas?

Comment: One thing that might make it tolerable is knowing that C-u and C-q will allow you to escape the next keystroke. I use C-u DEL to delete unwanted braces/quotes, and C-q ( or C-q ) to insert needed braces. You'll need that if you ever kill/yank or clipboard-yank a block of text into your buffer since that often causes unbalanced forms.

Comment: I wonder if the original author ever decided he liked paredit mode, or found a satisfactory way to turn it off.

Comment: you should mark your own answer as correct.

Answer (score 29):

Not an answer to your actual question, but give paredit mode a chance. I, too, was really annoyed with it automatically closing my parens, and refusing to delete just a single paren for me.

But doing this enables it to be certain at all times that the buffer is a well-balanced sexp, so it can perform many useful sexp-oriented tasks for you instead of just text-oriented tasks. For example, I use the following *all the time*:

- M-( to wrap a sexp with a new one, eg turn `(map f some-list)` into `(doto (map f some-list) println)`
- C-) to "slurp" another sexp into the current one, eg turn `(let [x 10]) (println x)` into `(let [x 10] (println x))`
- M-<UP> and/or M-r to pull the sexp at point a level "higher" in the source tree, destroying the thing that was wrapping it, eg to turn `(first (map f some-list))` into `(map f some-list)` or `(first some-list)`

There are zillions of useful features like this, that let you start editing *code* instead of *text*. And while there are plenty of excellent Lisp hackers who don't like paredit mode, I advise you not to decide against it before you realize the awesome stuff it can do for you.

Comment: I absolutely agree. I hated paredit at first, but I soon missed it enough in every other language mode that I bound some of paredit's functions in those modes too. For example, `M-(` for `paredit-wrap-round`, which encloses the following expressing in parens. Most programming language modes have a concept of sexps for that language's expressions and tokens, so the paredit functions often just Do The Right Thing.

Comment: Hm I have strange situation though, did some wrong editing and now I have "(" <block of code> "]" (parenthesis closed with square bracket) and I can't delete the square bracket because its closing the parenthesis! Can solve it selecting the block of code etc. but its annoying. Is there a quick solution for this situation?

Comment: Actually, I can't remove the wrong bracket with 'M-s' because then I get "Scan error: "Unbalanced parentheses"" o.O this is so sick there's absolutely no way to remove it, commenting, killing, etc., nothing works.

Comment: Ok, it's possible to turn it off with 'M-x paredit-mode' I'll probably turn it on again when my code is fixed. But it's useful to know how to turn it off for "emergencies".

Comment: A `C-u` prefix before a deletion action (backspace or `C-d`) makes it skip the paredit balancing rules, and `C-q` before any character inserts that character, ignoring any keybindings that would make it do something else.

Answer (score 16):

Found one trick that works. Before the elpa packages are loaded in `init.el`, add this hook to clojure mode:

```
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook (lambda () (paredit-mode nil)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I use clojure-mode through ELPA too, and it doesn't imply paredit. Maybe just uninstall it? I find clojure-mode, slime and slime-repl are the only packages I need to install on a clean EMACS to get clojure/swank/slime working.

I only tested this:

http://www.learningclojure.com/2010/08/clojure-emacs-swank-slime-maven-maven.html

a few weeks ago, and it still works fine.