# Emacs close paren jumps to already existing close-paren when editing clojure code

Tags: emacs, clojure, lisp

If having this piece of code in an emacs buffer:

```
(if (> x 5
    true
    false))
```

When I try to edit it in order to fix the parenthesis, something very annoying is happening! When I try to add a closing parenthesis to the if condition, emacs is making the cursor jump to the closing parenthesis after 'false' instead of adding a new parenthesis after `5`.

Is this part of some mode, maybe clojure-mode? Do you know how may I fix this? What is this useful for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're using paredit.  Did you install it like recommended on the [project page](https://github.com/technomancy/clojure-mode)?

As to what it's good for?  It's good for editing lists.  But you have to buy
into whe whole system, or *you'll end up really confused*.  See the [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit)
page.

Do you have this section in your `~/.emacs.el`?  Just remove it.

```lisp
;; (require 'paredit) if you didn't install via package.el
(defun turn-on-paredit () (paredit-mode 1))
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'turn-on-paredit)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have clojure-mode installed from the marmelade el repository and I am using it with leiningen projects through clojure-jack-in. I will later confirm if this is really a paredit thing and then mark this answer as correct.

Comment: how do I make clojure-mode work without paredit? Where is the customizationj group for this?

Comment: It doesn't look like `package.el` is automatically loading paredit, you must have added a customization for it.

Comment: plug: it's exactly situations like this that made me develop http://autopair.googlecode.com, which gives you good pairing, but not that kind of surprising and somewhat annoying behaviour. You might want to replace paredit with that.

Comment: I can vouch for Joao's autopair and *extended plug* yasnippet.  Both are firmly integrated into my Emacs workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, paredit is "different". It will always make sure your parenthesis balance. See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PareditCheatsheet .

For your code, place the cursor beneath the first closing parenthesis and press C-left. Repeat the exercise and it will have moved to where you want it.

Cut&paste (kill & yank in emacs lingo) also allow you to manually screw with the balanced parenthesis, so until you get used to paredit it may be easier to use. Good luck!

Comment: how do I make clojure-mode work without paredit? Where is the customizationj group for this?

Answer (score 1):

## how to verify that paredit is the offender

You can type `C-h k )` while in your Lisp buffer to see what `)` is bound to. If it is bound to `paredit-close-round` then yes paredit is the offender.

## how to disable paredit when you don't know what's triggering it

Try [auramo's answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5242449/1446335)

or if that doesn't work, try this:

```
(eval-after-load 'paredit
  '(defalias 'paredit-mode 'ignore))
```

If you are curious about what is triggering paredit-mode in your Emacs, use `M-x debug-on-entry RET paredit-mode RET`

## learning to live with paredit

But still I must encourage you to continue using paredit. Let's keep using paredit and let's see solutions for problems you posed. You asked "Do you know how may I fix this?" I'll just assume you are asking how to fix that if form. Marius Kjeldahl gave you solution which uses `paredit-forward-barf-sexp`, now in general, if you have some Lisp code where you see that some parens are in wrong places and you want to fix that, you can simply temporarily disable paredit-mode in that buffer (by typing `M-x paredit-mode`) and then fix your code and then enable paredit-mode again (by typing `M-x paredit-mode` again). Another thing to consider is that Emacs has undo, so if you arrive at `(if (> x 5 true false))` through some action, you can undo that action and start over. Undo is bound to `C-z` if you use CUA mode.

Still you might find bindings of C-left, C-right to be weird, so you might want to use the following setup:

```
(eval-after-load 'paredit
  '(progn
     ;; paredit-forward-barf-sexp is usually bound to <C-left>, C-}.
     ;; here we unbind it from <C-left>
     ;; so that one can continue to use <C-left> for movement.
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-left>") nil)

     ;; paredit-forward-slurp-sexp is usually bound to <C-right>, C-).
     ;; here we unbind it from <C-right>
     ;; so that one can continue to use <C-right> for movement.
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-right>") nil)

     ;; paredit-backward-kill-word is bound to M-DEL but not to <C-backspace>.
     ;; here we bind it to <C-backspace> as well
     ;; because most people prefer <C-backspace> to M-DEL.
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-backspace>") 'paredit-backward-kill-word)))
```

You asked "What is this useful for?" by which you may be asking two things:

- 1. Why is `paredit-close-round` useful?
- 2. Why does paredit have to bind `paredit-close-round` to `)` when it could have bound it to better keys?

Best way to think of `paredit-close-round` is to think of it as a counterpart to `C-M-u`. Move point to `|` in the following code and try press `C-M-u` several times to see what happens, and then move point to `|` again and try press `C-M-- C-M-u` (i.e. type `-u` while Control and Alt are on) several times to see what happens.

```
(when t
  (when t
    (blah)
    (blah))
  (when t
    (blah | blah)
    (blah))
  (when t
    (blah)
    (blah)))
```

`C-M-u` is useful for selecting expressions; in order to select an enclosing form or forms, you press `C-M-u` several times and then `C-M-SPC` several times. `C-M-- C-M-u` is useful for evaluating an enclosing form; you press `C-M-- C-M-u` several times and then `C-x C-e` to eval the enclosing form.

`paredit-close-round` basically does what `C-M-- C-M-u` does.

Why is it an OK thing that paredit binds `)` to a command that does something other than simply inserting a close paren? Because you are not supposed to insert a closing parenthesis by yourself. Whenever you insert an open paren, a close paren is also inserted automatically. Whenever you want to change `(blah) (blah)` to `((blah) (blah))`, you simply select the two blah forms and press `(`.